# AngularDart directive expression grammar for mustache and other directives

Tags: angularjs, parsing, dart, grammar, angular-dart

What is the grammar of expressions that are permitted within AngularDart mustaches `{{...}}` and other directives?

Comment: This is a limited subset of Dart expressions. It also has some deviatinos like null-handling. I have no idea if there is a documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an EBNF grammar for AngularDart expressions, in the same [notation](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.e59lyipdamf1) used in the [Dart Programming Language Specification](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html). These expressions can appear as arguments to Angular directives. While the grammar allows, e.g., a semicolon-separated list of expressions, assignments and conditionals, these will not be accepted by all directives---e.g., `ng-click` supports multiple expressions possibly with assignments, whereas the mustache directive `{{...}}` expects a single expression.

```sbnf
expressions: expression (';' expressions)?
expression:
    literal
  | id args?                        # variable or function
  | expression '.' id args?         # member
  | expression '|' id filterArg*    # filter
  | expression '[' expression ']'
  | preOp expression
  | expression binOp expression
  | expression '?' expression ':' expression
  | expression '=' expression           # assignment
args: '(' expressionList? ')'
filterArg: ':' expression
expressionList: expression (',' expression)?
literal:
    'null'
  | stringLiteral
  | numberLiteral
  | boolLiteral
  | '[' expressionList? ']'
  | '{' (keyValuePair (',' keyValuePair)? )? '}'
keyValuePair:
  expression ':' expression
```

The preOp and binOp are mainly those supported by Dart (though I will have to crosscheck that). There is a more nicely formatted version of the above [here](http://pchalin.blogspot.com/2014/03/angulardart-expression-grammar.html) (I could not get the MD to cooperate).